# makefile - dependency generator

Tags: makefile

I have two questions to a single problem that I am facing.

We have adopted non-recursive [boilermake](https://github.com/dmoulding/boilermake) for projects that use `gcc`. Going ahead we would like to use it for some other cross compilers say microchip C18 that do not support `-MM` / `MD` option for dependency generation.

I do not want to use makedepend since it's very old and adds in dependencies to makefiles; further, I believe it will be difficult separate objects from sources with makedepend.

Finally my questions:

1. Are there any readily available C/C++ dependency generators (similar to `-MM` 
   / `-MD` options)? (Build support is required for both Windows and Linux.)
2. Can I use `gcc` to only generate dependency files and do the actual compilation 
   with some other compiler? Will I run into any problems with this approach?
   If yes, what will be the changes required to the following

   ```
   # COMPILE_C_CMDS - Commands for compiling C source code.
   define COMPILE_C_CMDS
       @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
       $(strip ${CC} -o $@ -c -MD ${CFLAGS} ${SRC_CFLAGS} ${INCDIRS} \
           ${SRC_INCDIRS} ${SRC_DEFS} ${DEFS} $<)
       @cp ${@:%$(suffix $@)=%.d} ${@:%$(suffix $@)=%.P}; \
        sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
            -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < ${@:%$(suffix $@)=%.d} \
            >> ${@:%$(suffix $@)=%.P}; \
            rm -f ${@:%$(suffix $@)=%.d}
   endef
   ```

Comment: perhaps you could fit in makedepend in your workflow. I'm not familiar with boilermake, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't know of any, other than makedepend (but I don't entirely understand you aversion to it).

   Yes, definitely. The dependency handling is entirely a matter of GCC talking to GNUMake (I *hope* you're using GNUMake). The other compiler doesn't need to know anything about it.

```
# COMPILE_C_CMDS - Commands for compiling C source code.
define COMPILE_C_CMDS
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    # This line generates the dependency file foo.d
    $(strip ${CC} -o $@ -MM -MF ${@:%$(suffix $@)=%.d} ${CFLAGS} ${SRC_CFLAGS} \
        ${INCDIRS} ${SRC_INCDIRS} ${SRC_DEFS} ${DEFS} $<)
    # This one actually compiles. You must adapt the sytax for your compiler.
    $(strip ${SOME_OTHER_COMPILER} -o $@ -c ${CFLAGS} ${SRC_CFLAGS} ${INCDIRS} \
        ${SRC_INCDIRS} ${SRC_DEFS} ${DEFS} $<)
    @cp ${@:%$(suffix $@)=%.d} ${@:%$(suffix $@)=%.P}; \
     sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
         -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < ${@:%$(suffix $@)=%.d} \
         >> ${@:%$(suffix $@)=%.P}; \
         rm -f ${@:%$(suffix $@)=%.d}
endef
```

P.S. Your makefile will probably be cleaner if you do this as a pattern rule, not a defined command, but one thing at a time.

Comment: The defined recipe *does* get used in a pettern rule. The pattern rules are generated dynamically, though. Defining a canned sequence of commands that can be plopped down in any generated pattern rule makes it a lot cleaner.

Comment: @Dan Moulding: I hadn't thought of that. I'm accustomed to having a single pattern rule for e.g. `%.o`, and I don't trust makefile generators (I saw a 27,000+ line makefile once-- sometimes I still wake up in a cold sweat). But your point is valid.